# Pivot DataFrame - Python, Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have a DF that I want to pivot.

The pictures are representations of the DF I have, and how I want it (the wide is how I want it).

[image: How I want the DF to appear]

[image: How the DF looks right now]

Any tips on how i can make this happen using pandas?

I tried aggregating on debit, credit and period, then pivoting the DF, but got several "levels" of variables.
At the top was value, then underneath Q1, Q2, etc. The same for transaction and balance.

Comment: please provide a reproducible input and output, images are not accepted

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to get rid of that levels

```
data = data.pivot(index = 'Debit', columns = ["Period"], values = ["Credit","Value", "Transaction", "Balance"])
data.columns = [period[4:]+values  if values!="Credit" else "Credit" for values, period in data.columns.values]
data = data.loc[:, ~data.columns.duplicated()]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).